# Probability space of output voltage measured at the terminals of a power supply

Tags: probability, continuity

I have been asked to find probability space of some problems in terms of ( $\Omega$ , $\mathcal {F}, \mathcal{P}$ ). I know that how to write in terms of discrete sequences. For example, I will probably write $\Omega$ as             $\{ x : x \in x_i, i \in [1,10] , i \in \mathbb{N} ,x_i \in \{ 0,1 \} \} $ for the sample space of "Ten identical systems are branded as working or non working". The $ \mathcal{F}$ is probably all subsets of $ \Omega$ . And P is probability of subsets of $ \mathcal{F} $. So how do I approach this supposedly continuous time case. I know that it will be something of $ V+ \Delta V $. But I am just not getting how to write it.

Comment: Why exactly are you interested in finding the probability space and what exactly is your problem you wish to find the space for?

Comment: I need to find the probability space for the event that we are measuring voltage at the terminals of a power supply. I know that it is in some interval between V- delV and V + del V. But I do not know the exact terminology of how to write it in continuous time. I know how to write it in discrete time but not how to find it in continuous time.

Comment: I will need it to find things like probability voltage is in between certain values. And also that probability voltage exceeds certain error limits.

Comment: I could be wrong, but i think youre confusing the support of random variables with a probability space. If you have $N=10$ random variables that take on values in $S=\{0,1\}$, where $P(X_i=1)=p=1-P(X_i=0)$, for $i=1,...,N$ then you just described a typical (finite) Bernoulli process with support in $S^N$. No where in preceding sentence did I define $\Omega$ and the probabilities of any event related to this process can be calculated without any mention of the underlying probability space. The same goes for continuous random variables.

Comment: Of course, when you arent dealing with random variables, and solely talking about events, then you need to know the sample space to correctly determine all of the events and their probabilities (in finite cases, through combinatorics).